# Удаление дубликатов из списка состоящего из словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

В процессе список сортируется по ключу score и уже по ключу track необходимо удалить дубликаты, т.е. между двух одинаковых значений track оставить с наибольшим значением score.

```py
testlist = [
          {'score': 67.567, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}, 
          {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
          {'score': 15, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
          {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'}
          ] 
testlist = sorted(testlist, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)
```

Новый список должен иметь следующий вид:

```py
newlist = [
          {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
          {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}
          ]
```

Есть идеи решения подобной задачи? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```
testlist = [
    {'score': 67.567, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 15, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'}
]


def my_key(d: dict):
    return d['track'], d['score']


new_list = sorted(testlist, key=my_key, reverse=True)
answ_list = []
temp = ''
for my_dict in new_list:
    if temp != my_dict['track']:
        answ_list.append(my_dict)
    temp = my_dict['track']
print(answ_list)
```

Вывод

```
[{'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'}, {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свой вариант. Я буду использовать промежуточный словарь `result_dict`, который будет содержать `ключ = название трэка`, а `значение = это числовое значение`.  В сортировке нет необходимости
до обработки

```py
result_dict = {}

for item in testlist:
    if result_dict.get(item["track"]):
        if item["score"] > result_dict[item["track"]]:
            result_dict[item["track"]] = item["score"]
    else:
        result_dict[item["track"]] = item['score']

print(result_dict)

# OUT
# {'03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents': 69, '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents': 120}
```

И теперь можем привести к листу того формата, что нам нужен

```py
result_list = []

for key, value in result_dict.items():
    result_list.append(dict(score=value, track=key))


print(result_list)

# OUT
# [{'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}, 
#  {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'}]
```

а вот теперь можно отсортировать

```py
result_list = sorted(result_list, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
[{'track': a, 'score': max(d['score'] for d in b)} for a, b in groupby(sorted(testlist, key=lambda x: x['track']), key=lambda x: x['track'])]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `testlist = [
    {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 15, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 67.567, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
]` вот с таким набором попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import Tuple
from pprint import pprint
testlist = [
    {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 15, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 67.567, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
]

# сортируем по возрастанию наибольшее значение должно оказаться последним
s_list = sorted(testlist, key=lambda x: x['score'])


# Поскольку каждый из словарей списка состоит из 2-х элементов
# имеющих значения, которые можно использовать как ключи словаря
# преобразуем значения словарей списка в словари, где ключом будет
# значение `track`, а значением будет значение `score.
# Поскольку при создании словаря итерацией каждый значение каждого
# существующего ключа будет заменено следующим значением совпадающего ключа

def val_to_dict(item: dict) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    return item.get('track'), item.get('score')


new_dict = dict(map(val_to_dict, sorted(testlist, key=lambda x: x['score'])))


# ну и осталось развернуть в исходный вид

def dict_to_val(item: Tuple[str, float]):
    k, v = item
    return {
        'track': k,
        'score': v
    }


filtered_list = list(map(dict_to_val, new_dict.items()))
pprint(
    filtered_list
)
```

```latex
[{'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
 {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}]
```

---

А теперь покороче )

```py
from pprint import pprint

testlist = [
    {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 15, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
    {'score': 67.567, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'},
]

pprint(
    [
        dict((('track', t), ('score', s))) for item in [
        dict(tuple(reversed(i.values())) for i in sorted(testlist, key=lambda x: x['score']))
    ] for t, s in item.items()
    ]
)
```

```latex
[{'score': 120, 'track': '03 Greedo - Dead Presidents'},
 {'score': 69, 'track': '03 Greedo & Kenny Beats - Dead Presidents'}]
```